# How to echo a PHP Code After the Content

Tags: plugins, php, posts, html, the-content

i wanted to execute a code after the Content of each blog post. I just want it to be on posts and not on pages. I could execute simple html by the method but could not put the following content. Please help me out with a code to execute the following code at the end of content.

The code is simple in sense, but unlike most people who would echo html i need to have a mixture of php, JS and HTMl echoed after my content. The solution seems simple but i could not figure it out.

```
    <div class="css">
<?php if ( should_display_link() ) : ?>
[subscribe-author-button]
<?php echo '<a class="btn" style="background-color:#1f1fff; border-radius:100px;" href="'.site_url('chat/').'?new-message&to='.get_the_author_meta( 'user_login' ).'">Chat</a>' ; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
[simple-author-box]
<?php if ($post->post_status == "publish")  { ?>
<h4>[post-views]</h4>
<?php   }  else {echo "<span></span>";} ?> 
<?php if ( should_display_link() ) : ?>
<a class="btn" href="https://adityaagarwal3.typeform.com/to/Lin6FB" data-mode="popup" style="background-color:#DB4437;color:white;border-radius:25px;" data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true data-submit-close-delay="5" target="_blank">Report Content </a> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm_share", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)){ js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my approach which is used to do your requirement:

```
function themename_your_content_after($content) {
    if( is_single() ):
    ob_start();
    ?>
     <div class="css">
    <?php if ( should_display_link() ) : ?>
    [subscribe-author-button]
    <?php echo '<a class="btn" style="background-color:#1f1fff; border-radius:100px;" href="'.site_url('chat/').'?new-message&to='.get_the_author_meta( 'user_login' ).'">Chat</a>' ; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    [simple-author-box]
    <?php if ($post->post_status == "publish")  { ?>
    <h4>[post-views]</h4>
    <?php   }  else {echo "<span></span>";} ?> 
    <?php if ( should_display_link() ) : ?>
    <a class="btn" href="https://adityaagarwal3.typeform.com/to/Lin6FB" data-mode="popup" style="background-color:#DB4437;color:white;border-radius:25px;" data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true data-submit-close-delay="5" target="_blank">Report Content </a> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm_share", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)){ js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $code_content = ob_get_clean();
    $content .= $code_content;
    endif;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'themename_your_content_after');
```

Comment: Thanks. Will let you know in a few minutes, if it works

Comment: It will output the code after every post content on the single post page. So if you have any “related posts” on that site, they will also get appended.

Comment: It worked well. The code is executed before the related posts and comments section at my site and that is as expected. Thanks

Comment: Great @AdityaAgarwal. Good Luck!